# regain html after emptying it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have an if/else loop inside my jQuery. I need to hide HTML on my text box inside my if portion and regain it at my else part. How can I do this using jQuery?

```
if (test == 1) {
    $(#id).html(""); //code to hide html
} else {
    //code to regain
}
```

code to hide html will works fine,but how to regain the code after emptying it?

Comment: Store it in a variable before clearing it...?

Comment: @Rory is there any jquery function? like empty()??

Comment: You can use the getter of `html()` and save it to a variable before you clear it. Seeing your HTML would really help here, along with directions of what values you're trying to save.

Answer (score 1):

you can't regain lost HTML unless you have saved it somewhere,

you can either show/hide the element

```
if(test==1){
   $(#id).hide();
}
else{
   $(#id).show();
}
```

or you can store the values somewhere in a variable

```
var html = "";
if (test == 1) {
    html = $(#id).html(); 
    $(#id).html( "" ); 
} else {
    $(#id).html( html ); 
}
```

or set it to localstorage (if you browser supports it)

```
if (test == 1) {
    localStorage.setItem("savedHTML", $(#id).html()) ; 
    $(#id).html( "" ); 
} else {
    $(#id).html( localStorage.getItem( "savedHTML" ) ); 
}
```

Comment: @Miller in that case you need to store the html content in a variable or localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the complete html inside your div to a variable.

```
var htmlContent = $(#id).html();
```

Then in your else, you can assign it back.

```
$(#id).html(htmlContent);
```